# Is it possible to interface android mobile as GSM and GPS module with arduino based robotic applications?

Tags: arduino, usb

I want to built a robot and i need bunch of modules to track it like GSM/GPS Wifi and Camera
If i try to buy each of module separately it will cost me 300 dollar each aprox in Pakistan. On the other hand an android enable phone can be purchased on just 250$ having all of them. I was wondring if it is possible to interface android phones like (Huawaii or google nexus) with 8-bit microcontrollers or Arduino? The only port available with android phones are USB and Arduino supports USB. It is possible to some how attach both of them?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics.SE, great question. Although Josh perfectly answered your question, it is usually good practice to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer. Otherwise, you might discourage other people from answering your question.

Comment: Agree,  will defiantly take care of this next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need the Android Accessory API and [Android Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html). It is based off Arduino, and is open.

In general, if the phone + the ADK is cheaper than buying the components separately (I suspect it would be), then I'd buy the phone + ADK.

Your other option is to buy a phone, and a bluetooth shield for a microcontroller, then use the bluetooth connection to send data between the phone and microcontroller.

Comment: Alternatively if you're into signal processing (or just plain hate yourself) you can use the Android PCM libraries to repurpose the audio jack as a makeshift UART. I've only done this half-duplex with an MSP430 (and did so for lack of USB on the MSP430) so I can't comment on Arduino-specific implementation or talking back to the phone over the mic connector, but the only other hardware you need is a comparator and some passive components.